# Trying to learn batch script, what does this do: /letter?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting, command-prompt

Here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
xcopy c:\testsource c:\testbackup /m /e /y
```

So I know that "xcopy c:\testsource c:\testbackup" copies the files in the testsource directory and pastes them in the testbackup directory, but what does the "/m /e /y" do? Can you explain what each individual part of this section of code does?

Also, would you mind telling me where I could look up explanations of syntax like this on my own in the future so I don't have to keep asking simple questions like this (a command for command prompt, maybe online database of commands and explanations, just something more efficient than google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in batch you first enter the command to be excuted, and then supply the arguments. Each command can be seen as an own small programm.

you are calling the command `xcopy` and supply those five arguments to it.

A documentation can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/cc771254.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

you can also type in `help COMMAND`, for example `help xcopy`, to see a full list of arguments which can be passed to the command

Answer (score 1):

when in doubt, use the mighty `/?` behind most commands to get more information and extra switches. i.e: `xcopy /?` additionally, information on the `/m /e` and `/y` switches:
`xcopy /M`           Copies only files with the archive attribute set,
               turns off the archive attribute. `xcopy /e` Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. and `xcopy /y` Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
hope that helped!